# What is the difference between CompletedTaks and TotalComactionCompleted in Cassandra JMX?

Tags: cassandra, datastax

My goal is to add see completed compaction tasks and here I found the following values in an empty cluster( default DSE Cassandra installation of 4.8.14):

```
CompletedTasks = 1412
TotalCompactionsCompleted = 4
```

I am trying to figure out Cassandra JMX and was reading the documentation at
https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Metrics#compaction

```
Under org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Compaction,name=(Metric name)
> CompletedTasks : Estimated number of completed compaction tasks.
> TotalCompactionsCompleted : Estimated number of completed compaction tasks.
```

Can anyone please tell me what the differences are between those?

Thanks.

Comment: The only thing I can add is that `CompletedTasks` is increasing to the rate of 80/m on a 3 nodes idle cluster.

Comment: Explanations from the the [cassandra user mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/2cad65aba4fb035378591ef007ee68ccaf23a2c025aaaf7e7512d364@%3Cuser.cassandra.apache.org%3E).